# Selecting sequence results in "No Joins Given"

Tags: querydsl

I am trying to select nextval from an oracle sequence but I keep getting "No joins given".

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em_;

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em_);
Long nextVal = query.uniqueResult(SqlExpressions.nextval("USER_ID_SEQ");
```

I found [this commit](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/commit/385035ae40712d5dcdb6564b46c6e58df7160eb4) that enables "from-less queries", but the IllegalArgumentException I'm seeing is originating in JPAQueryBase which doesn't appear to be modified in that commit.

Timo has an [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/Qm2beSA52iY):

> `long result = query.uniqueResult(SQLExpressions.nextval("SEQ_1") );`

but that isn't working for me.

I'm using querydsl 3.3.3 with Hibernate 4.2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from-less queries are supported in JPA native queries, for Querydsl this would be

```
SQLTemplates templates = ...
JPASQLQuery query = new JPASQLQuery(em_, templates);
Long nextVal = query.uniqueResult(SQLExpressions.nextVal("USER_ID_SEQ");
```

Comment: Our product supports multiple databases. Is there a way to make this work in a more vendor-neutral fashion?

Comment: Getting the next value of a sequence is implemented in Querydsl is a vendor-neutral way or do you mean id generation abstractions?

Comment: Abstracting the id generation. I just want to be able to fetch the next value regardless of whether it's H2, oracle, or PostgreSQL. That's why I was attempting to use the JPAQuery object. I know hibernate lets you specify @ SequenceGenerator but that only works in conjunction with @ Id.

Comment: Timo, doesn't Querydsl know what kind of database it's talking to?

Comment: Yes, it does. nextVal abtracts the sequence nextval operation, but not id handling in general, which involves more than syntax, e.g. for autogenerated ids.

Comment: If Querydsl abstracts the sequence nextval operation, then why do I need to provide a SQLTemplate?

Comment: SQLTemplates provides the abstraction.

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is that since querydsl knows what kind of database I'm talking to, I feel that it should just select the appropriate SQLTemplate.

Comment: The SQLTemplates subclass is the RDBMS engine specific dialect, maybe that wasn't clear.

Comment: Right. I understand that. Maybe an example scenario will clear this up: My application is talking to an Oracle database, querydsl knows it's talking to an oracle database, then I say "fetch the nextval from a sequence". Querydsl says "Which template do you want me to use?". I don't understand why I need to say "SqlTemplates template = new OracleTemplate();" when querydsl knows it's talking to an Oracle database.

Comment: Even though this isn't my favorite solution, it does work so I'll make it the answer.

Comment: Querydsl doesn't inspect the JDBC connection (or EntityManager) to know that it talks to Oracle, OracleTemplates is where that info comes from.